# tinyMCE wrap element in a div

Tags: html, tinymce

I am using tinymce 3.3.6 (in Drupal) and I need a way to highlight multiple paragraphs and wrap them in a new div with a class.

e.g.

```
<p>bob</p>
<p>bob</p>
<p>bob</p>
```

will become (after highlighting and doing something)

```
<div class="accordion">
<p>bob</p>
<p>bob</p>
<p>bob</p>
</div>
```

At the moment, if I just highlight everything and try and add the class it simply becomes:

```
<p class="accordion">bob</p>
<p class="accordion">bob</p>
<p class="accordion">bob</p>
```